# Is it possible to pass extra data with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is simple. Is it possible to somehow pass extra data with `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` which the `Activity` receiving the `Intent` in it's `onActivityResult()` can read out?

For now I have tried to pass some data over with some standard `putExtra()` but that data disappears on it's way to my activity.
Using following code to setup intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(CURRENT_REQUEST_CODE_TAG, getTargetRequestCode());
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_SIGNAL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And I as I said, the extra data has disappeared when I get the intent in my activity. Is there some way of flagging or setup the intent so it would keep it's extra data or something else that I missing out?

If this isn't possible, are there any other kind of default/standard way of doing this? Note. I would not like to use `Shared Preferences´ for this.

Thanks!

**Update**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int currentRequestCode = data.getIntExtra(CURRENT_REQUEST_CODE_TAG, -1);
}
```

In my onActivityForResult() the `getIntExtra()`always returns the default value of -1, not the one I configured my intent with, which should be value 9 or 10. This tells me that the extra data has been lost, and a debuggin of the data object confirms my suspicions, the intent argument doesn't contain any extra data.

It seems like the intent I send isn't the same that get received in my onActivityResult(). I understand this behaviour because in my case the default Android file chooser is opened and let's the user chose a file of correct MIME type, and when the user selects a file I guess a new Intent is created with the URI to the selected file, but why does the extra data disappear, shouldn't it be kept?

Comment: Im curious: have You tried setting action to generic Intent? Like { Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); intent.putExtra(...) } , plus You might want to check question # 25622235

Comment: I recommends you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554156/3763032), or see my [full gist here](https://gist.github.com/mochadwi/032bbc39e6341ecff1deb3a2545e7c0a) @Robert

Answer (score 2):

I don´t think that you can pass your data as Extras through Intent that has action as `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. But you can try do it something like this:

```
    Intent extraIntent = getActivity().getIntent() != null ? getActivity().getIntent().getIntent() : new Intent();
    extraIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_LOCATION_ID, loc.getId());
    extraIntent.putExtra(CURRENT_REQUEST_CODE_TAG, getTargetRequestCode());

    getActivity().setIntent(extraIntent);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_SIGNAL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and `onActivityResult` you can read your data from activity`s Intent:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        int currentRequestCode = getIntent().getIntExtra(CURRENT_REQUEST_CODE_TAG, -1);
    }
```

Comment: this assumes that there's only 1 activity that can be started at a time. The 2nd one overrides the intent...

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try the code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(CURRENT_REQUEST_CODE_TAG, getTargetRequestCode());
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_SIGNAL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now override the onActivityResult method in the fragment you call the above code

Comment: Would it possible to see the code in your onActivityResult?

Comment: added onActivityResult() and some further info.