# Passing extras with intent while using intent with action ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

I have a code to get get a audio from storage and save the uri to the audio selected.
Also I want to pass an additional parameter `TimeZoneOfDay` with the intent.
here is the code to do that

```
  Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
  intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
  intent_upload.putExtra(TimeZoneOfDay,2);
  // Bundle b = new Bundle();
  //b.putInt(TimeZoneOfDay,2);
  intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);




 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

        Log.e(Tag, "Onactivity result called");
        if(requestCode == 1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "file choosen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Bundle b = data.getExtras();

                Log.e(Tag, "dcs "+data.hasExtra(TimeZoneOfDay)+ String.valueOf(b!=null));
```

I also want to put an extra in my intent TimeZoneofDay. 
However,  `data.hasExtra(Timezone)` is showing `false` and `data.getExtras()` is `null`.

How to properly pass the parameter `TimeZoneOfDay` ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to properly pass the parameter TimeZoneOfDay ?

You don't. You did not write the app that is responding to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. You cannot force that app to put a value in an extra of the result `Intent`.

Instead, hold `2` in a field, and use that field in your `onActivityResult()`. Also, since your process might be terminated while you are in the background, hold onto that `2` in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Camera/FileProvider), I hold onto a `File` object as a field, then use that for a `Uri` for use with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. That way, in `onActivityResult()`, I know where the image should reside.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into this answer to check whether you aren't missing anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554156/6284141

Comment: As shown there, they are using data.getExtras().getString("NAME OF THE PARAMETER"); which will simply crash my app as data.getExtras() is null in my case.            I think is that the intent has a extra TimeZoneofDay which launches the action. However, ones a audio file is selected a new intent is made with the uri of the file and thus it does not contain the extra TimeZOneOfDay.   Does this make any sense ?

Comment: in my case this is works. see here for full gists: https://gist.github.com/mochadwi/032bbc39e6341ecff1deb3a2545e7c0a